# No article in the construction 'hire of ....'

Tags: definite-articles

One sentence in a recent newspaper article reads

> Liverpool spent the last fortnight sorting out their upstairs departments, **with hires of CEO of Football Michael Edwards and sporting director Richard Hughes**, and now the Reds will set their sights on stepping up the renovation of the front of house.

This is the first time I've seen the construction 'hire(s) of...'. And I would use it without 'the' too. But I don't understand why.

Comment: The answers seem to suggest that I'm the only one, but to me that sentence sounds incorrect. I would use "*the* hires."

Answer (score 2):

[Longman Dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/hire) brings out the fact that there are at least two polysemes of the noun **hire**:

> *hire*  [noun]
>
> 1 [uncountable] [British English] an arrangement by which someone
> borrows something for a period of time in exchange for money [synonym:
> *rental*]
>
> - *All our equipment is available for hire.*
> - *The engine is on hire from a local firm.*
> - *We want to keep hire charges on plant and machinery to a minimum.*
> - [*They also offer bicycle hire.*]
>
> [note that this usage often occurs in prepositional phrases or as a
> premodifier, or a premodified head noun]
>
> 2 [countable] [American English] someone who starts to work for an
> organization [synonym: recruit]
>
> - *The firm’s hires included economist Richard Hoey and investment strategist Joseph Cohen.*
> - *Nearly half Andersen’s new hires are women.*

The second sense is obviously being imported into the UK. The way such changes work, it is quite possible that the first sense will be countified also (with *hires* = *instances of hiring*), though that may well be some time off.

Answer (score 1):

a hire (noun) is someone you hire for a job in BrE and AmE.

There is no article because the plural is used.
We say: I like apples, with an s. Same idea. BUT: We had **a new hire** last week. **The new hire** seems very diligent.

> "Liverpool spent the last fortnight sorting out their upstairs
> departments, with hires of CEO of Football Michael Edwards and
> sporting director Richard Hughes, and now the Reds will set their
> sights on stepping up the renovation of the front of house." is from
> the Daily Mail, a British publication.

This has nothing to do with hire as rent. The BrE says: cars for hire, AmE says: cars for rent

Comment: Did you mean to put "is from..." inside the quotation? Who are you quoting?

Comment: @Barmar I said that it is from the Daily Mail. No, "is from" is not inside the quote.

Answer (score 0):

The general meaning of the word has been exposed in this [preceding answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/620901/349876). The question of whether to use an article, and which to use is rather involved, and it will not be futile to go methodically through the following two sections of *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language* (Quirk et al., 1985) in order to grasp this question thoroughly.

The zero article in this case has the same value as "some" because there is no categorial meaning intended as made clear by the context. "The" would modify the meaning as its use would imply that all the hires were involved.

> (**CoGEL § 5.39**) **The zero article compared with unstressed *some***
> With plural count nouns and with noncount nouns, the indefinite article does
> not occur […]. The zero article is used instead:
>
> - Have you ever eaten *roasted chestnuts*?
> - *Milk* is good for you.
> - Do you like *folk music*?
>
> But the plural or noncount equivalent of a/an is sometimes the unstressed
> determiner *some* /sam/. Contrast:
>
> - I have just bought *a melon*.                 [1]
> - *some melons*.        [1]
> - *some melon*.         [1]
> - ?*melons*.                 [1]
> - She has become *a vegetarian*.                       [2]
> - They have become *vegetarians*.                 [2]
> - *some vegetarians.      [2]
>
> In the negative, unstressed *any* is the equivalent of *some* […], so that a contrast may be observed between [3] and [4]:
>
> - I haven't bought *any books*.           [3]
>                                 ?*books*.                 [3]
> - They haven't become *vegetarians*.                [4]
> - **any vegetarians*.      [4]
>
> The difference between the uses of zero and of *some* may be summarized
> as follows. Unstressed *some*, although it is sometimes considered a plural
> article, actually keeps its quantifying function, and indicates reference to a
> specifiable (though indefinite) quantity or amount. (Thus in [1], the speaker
> does not tell us the number of melons, but in principle the number could be
> found out.) The zero article, in contrast, indicates simply the category of the
> objects, etc referred to. So *vegetarians* in [4] names a category of persons, and the sentence simply indicates that the people referred to by *they* belong to that category.
> […]

> (**5.40**) Sometimes *some* and zero are both acceptable; in other cases one of them is less acceptable, or even quite unacceptable. In the following two examples, *some* would be unacceptable:
>
> - These shoes are made of leather.     [1]
> - I've always preferred coffee to tea. [2]
>
> In [1], the speaker is merely interested in the type of material of which the
> shoes are made: the quantity is irrelevant. In [2], the interest focuses on the
> two types of drink, and it is irrelevant to consider particular quantities.
> In other cases, the introduction of some would necessitate a sharp difference
> in meaning, *eg*:
>
> - Joe's been chasing *women* ever since he was young. [3]
>
> In [3], *some women* would produce the incongruous impression that Joe has
> been steadfastly chasing the same group of women, rather than that he is an
> incorrigible Don Juan.
> The distinction we have to draw, then, is between the CATEGORIAL
> meaning of zero, and the QUANTITATIVE meaning of *some*. It can now be seen that the generic meaning of the zero article, as in *Tigers are fierce animals* […], is no more than a special variant of this categorial meaning. But it is still worth separating generic reference, where we could substitute *all tigers* with little change of effect, from the specific categorial reference of sentences like [3], where clearly there is no claim that all women have been chased by Joe […].
> As has already been hinted, the choice between zero and *some* is sometimes
> more a matter of focus than of clear contrast of meaning. There are many
> situations in which either choice could be made, with only a minor alteration
> of the force. Compare:
>
> - Would you like (*some*) *coffee* or (*some*) *tea*?             [4]
> - I've been writing (*some*) *letters* this morning.           [5]
> - We have just received (*some*) *news* from Moscow.  [6]
>
> The variant without some will focus on the category as a whole; eg [4] is asking about two kinds of drink, and [5] is concerned with a kind of activity,
> *viz* the activity of writing letters. But when *some* is added, the focus changes to whatever quantities of tea and coffee, or of letters, that the speaker has in mind.